# Permission Denied

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-permissions

My app is crashing when I call `insert` on the contentProvider class and I get a permission denied error. How do I set the permission??

```
01-13 23:41:15.071      467-467/system_process W/ActivityManager﹕ Permission denied: checkComponentPermission() owningUid=10065
01-13 23:41:15.071      467-467/system_process W/ActivityManager﹕ Permission Denial: opening provider net.kritico.todolist.ToDoContentProvider from ProcessRecord{a784a9c0 1669:net.kritico.kriticoads/u0a10069} (pid=1669, uid=10069) that is not exported from uid 10065
```

My manifest is as below

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="9"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
<!-- Used to request banner and interstitial ads. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<!-- Used to avoid sending an ad request if there is no connectivity. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="net.kritico.kriticoads.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <!-- Activity required to show ad overlays. -->
    <activity
        android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
                                     android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|
    screenSize|s   mallestScreenSize" />
    <activity
        android:name="net.kritico.kriticoads.ToDoItemActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_to_do_item" >
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to declare the ContentProvider to your manifest inside of your application tag. [Declaring Content Provider](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/provider-element.html)

Also see [Declaring Content Provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8300603/declaring-content-provider)